# Song played on "Parasyte The Maxim" Episode 6 at time 16min30s

Tags: music, parasyte

I'm looking forward the name of the song played in the 6 episode at 16min30s.
It's when Migi explains that She has to sleep for 4 hours as She has healed him.
This song appears regularily in the episodes, and it is not in the OST (or I didn't find it).

Comment: You'll have a much better chance of getting an answer if you describe what's happening in the scene.

Comment: is it this one? https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DVl9XNs8jqw

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The song you are looking for is the Migi Theme by [Ken Arai](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ken_Arai)

[You can listen to it here](https://youtu.be/pcScX2Rh6qM)

This song does not seem to be included in the currently released OST